# Can Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange provide QQ or Weibo log in?

Tags: support, feature-request, china

I'm in China, where we haven't been able to visit Facebook or Twitter for a long time, as you know, and we haven't even been able to visit Google without help since this June. I think there are lots of people living in China, using this site. And I've no doubt there will be more and more.

So can you provide QQ or Weibo login to make it more convenient for us? Everybody in China uses QQ, and most people use Weibo here. And both of them provide OAuth login:

- [QQ](http://wiki.open.qq.com/wiki/website/OAuth2.0%E7%AE%80%E4%BB%8B),
- [Weibo](http://open.weibo.com/authentication/).

Comment: Can't you use OpenID login URL directly?

Comment: I cannot visit my google profile, so I cannot get my OpenID login URL.

Comment: @worldask: OpenID isn't a Google thing. QQ & Weibo probably provide you with an OpenID URL for your accounts there.

Comment: I support your feature request, because a lot of users for non-technical SE sites might benefit from the addition of these, I don't see any harm in it, and it shouldn't take much dev time to add the support for these two.

Comment: Should this not be moved to [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Good luck, hopefully the login method gets implemented before Stack Overflow gets banned from China's filters too.

Comment: @Mat, Konstantin - OAuth isn't the same as OpenID. There typically isn't a user-specific URL, you gotta bounce to the provider site and then come back with an auth response.

Comment: This is ... probably unlikely. We are already having a heck of a time supporting a myriad existing providers. I don't see us adding two more... then again, China is pretty big. Not immediately sure how to gauge effort vs reward here.

Comment: @AnnaLear [Solution: SE creates a truly universal login system that everyone can use and covers existing ones.](http://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: @AnnaLear Why don't you focus effort on unborking the existing system before piling on more crap? Of course this is great for people, but unborking should happen first!

Comment: @bjb568 Unborking sounds marvelous until you consider the fact that that basically means "support nothing except perhaps Google and Facebook as well as our own logins". It's not that simple when you have legacy accounts. MyOpenID shut down over 6 months ago and we are still seeing support cases from people who had that as their only credential.

Comment: @AnnaLear Sigh… so force people to add another login or threaten to delete their account or something? Them slowing down the development that concerns a community of millions of users is not acceptable, it deserves poking! (with a sharp stick)

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh, you mean the accounts aren't recoverable at all?

Comment: @bjb568 Ohhh I see what you're saying. Sorry, misread it at first. Funnily enough, threatening people with account deletion doesn't work well. ;)  We did email folks to tell them that their only credential was MyOpenID before it shut down, but not everyone noticed/responded/etc.

Comment: @bjb568 There are two defunct providers that I know of - MyOpenID and ClaimID. Anyone can also make their own self-served provider... The bottom line is, if you can reach us at all, you can sign up for an SE OpenID, which is similar enough to just creating a login/password for any other site that we don't *need* to keep implementing explicit niche provider support.

Comment: @AnnaLear Anyway, by "unbork" I meant global SE id (no more single-site logins) and all other uids updated (including in comments!).

Comment: Why not allow a user to use a Stack Exchange ID (separate registration), that appears to a user as a standalone user+pass pair? Or is that gone by now?

Comment: @AnnaLear It would be kinda kool to do some of the stuff that github does: since all providers in reality use a set base of methods, from OAUTH to openID you could actually allow people to write configuration files for these base protocols and upload them to github or something as pull requests which can then be vetted and used on the site itself as login methods, of course this could introduce big problems but still would be a kool thing to do and would mean you can get other people worry about the login hairball

Comment: @hexafraction That's kinda/sorta what Stack Exchange OpenID is. Treating it like a username/password is causing us some other headaches, but it does the job well enough for the moment.

Comment: Hi, I'm from China too. I don't think it's a good idea to link any Chinese local web services with StackOverflow, since the Chinese government can retrieve your personal information directly from the local services. And I don't think it's difficult to break the internet restrict of China.

Comment: @LouisZhu But everybody use QQ or Wechat, don't you?

Comment: @LouisZhu you make a good point plus these services go up and down whenever your government feels like you have gone a bit far

Comment: @worldask I don't. I come from Hong Kong by the way. Tencent and Weibo services are unpopular at my city.

Comment: @Unihedron You're out of GFW, you don't know our pain...

Comment: @worldask I do. __I was there.__ Anyway, "_everybody use_" is not a good objective statement - speak for yourself or provide evidence / proofs to back up your points.

Comment: @Unihedron QQ provides a [online user statistics](http://im.qq.com/online/), there are more than 200 billions user are online now. Yes it's far less than the population of China, but I think guys here understand 'everybody' means at least 'a great many', maybe 'most of'. As some foreigner said that everybody use Facebook, I knew what 'everybody' means.

Comment: I think it is a case of "everyone" uses since there is no other choice, right?

Comment: I think it's because of my poor English... I won't make a universal judgment easily when I speak Chinese.